# An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_fetch_array

Tags: php, authentication, session, sqlsrv

I'm using PHP web service for my android development back end. The connection with php and MSSQL Server are successful but unfortunately I stuck at this part:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connect.php";
$user_name = $_POST["username"];
$user_pass = strval($_POST["password"]);
//echo $user_name;
//echo $user_pass;

//$user_name = "admin";
//$user_pass = "admin";
$mysql_qry="SELECT ID, Password FROM user WHERE (ID = '" . $_POST["username"] . "'  AND Password = '" . $_POST["password"] . "')";
$result= sqlsrv_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
$row  = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
if($row) {
$_SESSION["ID"] = $row['ID'];
header ('location:../createUser.php');
}else{
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

It shows error:  An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_fetch_array.

This is my login form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link
      href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body class="bg-gradient-primary">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Outer Row -->
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">
          <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
              <div class="row">
                <img class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block " src="img/Login.png">

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="p-5">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">
                        Welcome To DEMO 1
                      </h1>
                    </div>
                    <form class="user" method="POST" action="php/login.php">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="username"
                          class="form-control form-control-user"
                          id="exampleInputEmail"
                          aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                          placeholder="Enter Username..."
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="password"
                          name="password"
                          class="form-control form-control-user"
                          id="exampleInputPassword"
                          placeholder="Password"
                        />
                      </div>

                      <button
                        class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"
                        type="submit"
                      >
                        Login
                      </button>
                    </form>
                    <hr />

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I already check on the parameter and everything looks just fine. Why is the error keep occur?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one parameter in

```
$row  = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
```

So , change to

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Or , edit your query

```
$mysql_qry="SELECT ID, Password FROM user WHERE ID = '$user_name' AND Password = '$user_pass' ";
```

Comment: check my answer again

Answer (score 0):

Consdier the following:

- One possible explanation for your error is that you are concatenating user input to build the SQL statement. In fact, you are injecting your code. Never do this, always use prepared statements and parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. With PHP Driver for SQL Server, function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.
- You need to hash the passowrd, because at the moment you are passing the password as plain text. When the password is hashed, you may safely pass it to the database.
- Check the result from `sqlsrv_query()` execution.
- As a note, you may use `sqlsrv_has_rows()` function to check if the result set has one or more rows.

The next example, based on your code, may help to get your expected results:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connect.php";
$user_name = $_POST["username"];
$user_pass = strval($_POST["password"]);

$mysql_qry = "
    SELECT ID, Password 
    FROM user 
    WHERE ID = ? AND Password = ?
";
$params = array($user_name, $user_pass);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $mysql_qry, $params);
if ($result === false) (
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
)

if (sqlsrv_has_rows($result)) {
    // You don't even need to fetch the record, just use:
    // $_SESSION["ID"] = $user_name;
    // header ('location:../createUser.php');
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_fetch_array): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }
    $_SESSION["ID"] = $row['ID'];
    header ('location:../createUser.php');
} else {
    echo "User not found";
    exit;
}
?>
```